# Visual Studio plugin/extension to convert XML to YAML

Tags: visual-studio, yaml, azure-functions, openapi

I was wondering if there a simple way how to convert XML comments (triple forward slashes) to YAML. I checked the Visual Studio Marketplace and Nuget Gallery and did not find anything relevant.

To give you a high level picture I am developing a set of APIs on Visual Studio and then publishing them on Azure Functions. On Azure Funtions I have enabled OpenAPI definition which generates a YAML file. The problem is the YAML is quite basic and moreover I would like to update the YAML on Azure whenever I re-publish my APIs. Is there an automated how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool you're looking for is Swashbuckle.

> Seamlessly adds a Swagger to WebApi projects! Combines ApiExplorer and Swagger/swagger-ui to provide a rich discovery, documentation and playground experience to your API consumers.
>
> In addition to its Swagger generator, Swashbuckle also contains an embedded version of swagger-ui which it will automatically serve up once Swashbuckle is installed. This means you can complement your API with a slick discovery UI to assist consumers with their integration efforts. Best of all, it requires minimal coding and maintenance, allowing you to focus on building an awesome API!

Here's the [original version](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle). There's also a [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) which you should *probably* take a look at first, since...

> With the introduction of ASP.NET Core, I've now shifted my focus to the Core-specific project - Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.

Comment: I tried to implement Swashbuckle. I downloaded the Nuget package and followed some tutorials I found online. According to different sources upon installation it should have created a file for me but this wasn't the case for me. My project type is a class library and all of these tutorials were WebApi focused with the files WebApiConfig, RouteConfig, Global.asax etc. Not sure if it's making sense. I was not 100% sure this solution was the right one for me. I'll have a look at it again and check out the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and see if that is what I am looking for. Thanks